# Normal orientation does not show dot

Tags: mesh, normals

In a forum somebody showed how the normal orientation looks for him:

[image]

However for me it looks like this:

[image]

I don't have this yellow dot at the end (or is it the start???) of the normal, so I think I can not say whether the normal direction is correct, or can I?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have face select enabled in edit mode?

Comment: @gladys Yes, I do.

Comment: My guess is that you have a non-planar quad (or ngon) and the 'dot' is on the far side.

Comment: I'd call it the start since it's in the center of the face with the line protruding from it…

Comment: Note that this dot isn't needed to determine the direction the normal is facing. The base of the cyan line is always in the center of a face, so it's actually entirely coincidence that there is a dot there.

Answer (score 2):

The face indicator "dot" is displayed in Wireframe Shading or Solid Viewport Shading while Textured Solid is disabled in Properties panel Shading section.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're using *Textured* viewport shading. You need to select one of *Bounding Box*, *Wireframe*, *Solid*, or *Material* in order to see the face dots:

[image: screenshot of viewport shading selector with check marks showing which ones enable face dot viewing]

Also, if you have Textured Solid enabled under Shading in the properties panel, the face dots will only be shown if you are using Wireframe or Bounding Box viewport shading.

[image: screenshot of the properties panel with Shading > Textured Solid circled]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the size of the dots got messed up.  Just go to *user preferences* > *themes* > *3D view*:
[image]

And then scroll down and adjust the *face dot size* spinner:
[image]

Comment: It was at 4, I have cranked it up to 10, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: @tmighty  That's strange, I don't know what's wrong.  BTW, the dots have nothing to do with viewing the normals, the dots are shown when you are in face select mode whether you are viewing normals or not.